# Failed to start reload.service: Unit reload.service not found

Tags: 14.04, aws, tomcat

I have added this in tomcat service :

```
[Unit]
Description=Apache Tomcat 8 Servlet Container
After=syslog.target network.target

[Service]
User=tomcat
Group=tomcat
Type=forking
Environment=CATALINA_PID=/opt/tomcat/tomcat.pid
Environment=CATALINA_HOME=/opt/tomcat
Environment=CATALINA_BASE=/opt/tomcat
ExecStart=/opt/tomcat/bin/startup.sh
ExecStop=/opt/tomcat/bin/shutdown.sh
Restart=on-failure

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

And used this command:

```
systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl start tomcat
```

Am getting this error:

```
Failed to start reload.service: Unit reload.service not found.
```

Can Anyone help me.

Answer (score 1):

The error message you give would appear if you run this command:

```
$ sudo systemctl start reload 
Failed to start reload.service: Unit reload.service not found.
```

Check that you are indeed running the correct command for starting tomcat, which would be:

```
$ sudo systemctl start tomcat
```